# VS2017 cannot find System.Transactions

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to use TransactionScrope but VS 2017 Cannot identify  System.Transactions. I cannot find it under References.
When I try to add it manually using Add Reference I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have the dll. Then try adding the reference manually by clicking as shown below
https://ibb.co/jjFzZn

Then go to directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\

And then you should be able to scroll down and add the reference.

Comment: The dll is there. I am not sure what that screenshot you attached is this in VS2017? I cannot add a Reference manually because of that error

Comment: The screenshot I added is VS2017.

Try under solution explorer, right clicking add reference, as seen here https://ibb.co/ertHn7

Comment: That's the problem when I try to add the reference I get the error I attached in the screen shot